# Does the following sound natural: "Please hold the bottle upright! Don't tip it upside down as you might spill water in the stroller"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, phrase-request, idioms

[image]

A child's sitting in a stroller holding a bottle of water without a cap.

Is it natural to say to the child:

> "**Please hold the bottle upright! Don't tip it upside down as you might spill water in the stroller**"?

There are many issues that I need to think about.

-1st, "**Hold the bottle upright! don't tip it upside down**" is too much to express.

Depending on the amount of water in the bottle, if the water is a lot, it will spill if the bottle is tipped at a small angle (may be 20 or 30 degrees).

If the water is little, it will spill if the bottle is tipped at a greater angle (may be 90 or 100 degrees).

To say "**tip it upside down**" means "**to tip it at 180 degrees**" which is too much.

Similarly, to keep the water in the bottle, we don't need to "**hold the bottle upright!" extremely. If the water is a lot, you may hold it almost upright. Id the water is little, you may not tip it at a greater angle.

Do we have any idioms to be used with "**hold**" & "**tip**" to mean to keep the water inside the bottle?

-2nd, is it okay to say "**to spill water in the stroller**"? We often say "**to spill water on the floor**", so "**to spill in something**" sounds uncommon. Do you say "**to spill water on the seat of the stroller**"?

Comment: "Please hold the bottle upright so that the water does not spill." You are trying to say/explain too much in one sentence. It does not matter *where* the water spills, or how much water is in the bottle, or whether a stroller has a floor or a seat. Keep it simple.

Comment: If the child is as young as the one in the picture, you  should have used a capped bottle like the one they are holding. If the child is older than that one, they might understand "Don't tip it!".